# Laravel 5 datepicker multilanguage

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5.1, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using Laravel 5.1 and jquery datepicker:

```
 <script>
 $(function () {
        $('input[type=date]').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy'
        });

    });
  </script>
```

I have my page in 3 different langauges. Depending on the current language, which I get from Config::get('app.locale') it should change the language of the datepicker. Any ideas how this can be done? Thank you

Comment: Just an idea: You can change your language in your HTML lang attribute, add it in your view with 'the current locale', this way you can grab it with jquery and add a switch case based on your lang="en" attribute and change the date format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a hidden field with the current language

```
<input type="hidden" id="lang" vale="{{Config::get('app.locale')}}">
```

Use js to get that value and `$.datepicker.regional[lang]` to change the language of the datepiker

```
var lang = $('#lang').val();
$( "input[type=date]" ).datepicker( $.datepicker.regional[lang] );
```

Comment: Which javascript files I have to include in order to get a translation? Till now I have <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/ui/minified/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/i18n/datepicker-de.js"></script>

Comment: you don't need the last one